# How Can i execute something in one window and it happens on another (chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, user-interface, web

I want to make a GUI which opens in a pop-out window. It needs to be able to access the console from the original window.(aka needs to run commands from pop-out to the real window). maybe I could use jquery idk

```js
var win = window.open("", "Poppout", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=350,height=400,top="+(screen.height-400)+",left="+(screen.width-840));
win.document.body.innerHTML = `<button onclick="javascript:alert("success!")" >test</button>`
```

you can do this but it doesn't do anything

Anything works. Im testing as we speak so yeah, thats it for my question sure hope this is possible

Answer (score 0):

window.opener
it refers to the window object that .open() was ran on
[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)

Comment: bruh I told u that

Comment: @penguinpowerss nahhh

Comment: cap @Zastix bozo

Answer (score 0):

From your main page, you'll need native javascript window.parent :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <button onclick="parentLocation()">Open GUI</button>

    <script>
        function parentLocation() {
           window.open("", "Poppout", "width=350, height=400");
           alert(window.parent.location);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And if you run a script from the pop-up window, you'll need the javascript window.parent.opener property (or just parent.opener).

Source: [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp)

Comment: I'm sorry but I found a solution